# Finding the inverse of $a^9$ in a group $G$ when given the order of $a$ is $18$.

Tags: group-theory, elementary-number-theory

The order of $a$ is $18$, and I'm trying to find the inverse of $a^9$.

I know that $o(a^9)=\frac{o(a)}{\gcd(o(a),9)}\frac{18}{\gcd(18,9)}=2$.

I have also seen that $o(a)=o(a^{-1})$ from the properties of element order in a group.

I have tried to find which k satisfies $o(a^k)=\frac{18}{\gcd(o(a),k)}=2$ and I have seen that the order will be $2$ is when $9*k$ and $k$ is coprime to $18$.

Do that mean that the smallest $k\neq9$ that satisfies $o(a^k)=2$ will be the inverse of $a^9$ which is $a^{27}$ ?

Comment: If $a^{18}=e$ then $a^9\times a^9=e$.

Comment: Yes, $a^{27}$ would be an inverse of $a^9$.

Comment: @lulu yes I agree but I'm trying to write the inverse in a way of a^(some number)

Comment: Right....so the answer is $a^9$.

Comment: @lulu the inverse of $a^9$ is also $a^9$?

Comment: Of course.  Indeed $a^{27}=a^{18}\times a^9=e\times a^9=a^9$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:** For any element $g$ of any group $G$ with identity $e$, we have $$g^2=e\iff g=g^{-1}.$$

*Proof:* ($\Rightarrow$) Multiply on the left, say, by $g^{-1}$. ($\Leftarrow$) Multiply on the right, say, by $g$. $\square$

> But $e=a^{18}=(a^9)^2$, so $(a^9)^{-1}=a^9$.